# How to configure Opserver for SQL Server clusters

Tags: sql-server, json, cluster-computing, opserver

I am trying out Opserver to monitor SQL Server instances. No issue with configuring standalone instances, but when I tried to configure SQL Server clusters using the method documented here: http://www.patrickhyatt.com/2013/10/25/setting-up-stackexchanges-opserver.html

I am confused about where to put SQL Server cluster named instance and Windows node servers:

In the JSON code below:

```
{
"defaultConnectionString": "Data Source=$ServerName$;Initial     Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
"clusters": [
    {
     "name": "SDCluster01",
     "nodes": [
      { "name": "SDCluster01\\SDCluster01_01" },
      { "name": "SDCluster02\\SDCluster01_02" },
     ]
    },       
],
```

I assume SDCLuster01 is the instance DNS name and SDCluster01_01 and SDCluster01_02 are Windows node server names.

But what if I have a named instance (clustered) like SDCluster01\instance1?

I tried to configure it like this:

```
{
"defaultConnectionString": "Data Source=$ServerName$;Initial     Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
"clusters": [
    {
     "name": "SDCluster01\instance1",
     "nodes": [
      { "name": "SDCluster01\\SDCluster01_01" },
      { "name": "SDCluster02\\SDCluster01_02" },
     ]
    },       
],
```

But after deploying to Opserver it gave me this error message:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Any ideas on how to configure the JSON file correctly for SQL Server clusters?